pdfjs messes up with too long content
I have a small test project with vue 2 and pdfjs. The goal is to create a dynamic pdf-viewer with multiple columns and nice pagebreaks. Everything works great until the content of one "section" is too large. Then the "Previewer" takes the wrong content to render. He takes the root of the app and not the specific 'div'.
Here is the related codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/72haja/my-pagedjs-project/draft/crazy-breeze?workspaceId=077ecee0-9bf0-4363-83a3-727022027e42
The relevant html part is the following:
<div>
  ... 
  <div ref="myBook" class="book-content">
    <div class="book-container" :class="`cols-${cols}`">
      <section class="section-container"> ... </section>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div ref="previewContainer" class="preview-container"/> 
  ...
</div>

and the relevant javaScript to render the preview is the following:
...
mounted(){
  this.paged = new Previewer();
},
methods: {
  render {
    ...
    const contentElement = this.$refs.myBook.cloneNode(true); 
    const preview = this.$refs.previewContainer;
    this.paged.preview(contentElement, ['/page.css'], preview)
    ...
  }
}

Just paste an really long "lorem ipsum" into the text box and check the second "page" of the previewed pdf.
Has anyone an idea how to fix this?
